# The volume of a balloon has a radius with helium given by the function $f(r) = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^{3}$.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

So my goal in this problem is to find the Domain as well as establish what the dependent and independent variables are.

I have established that the dependent variable is V for volume, and the independent variable is radius (in meters).

My problem now lies with the domain.

So a small constraint : The problem dictates that the balloon holds up to $1m^3$ of helium.

Now, back to the issue of domain:

Specifically, how to find the domain of something that is $f(r) = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ such that the balloon can hold $1m^3$ of helium? What I would intuitively do is get the right side of the equation to equal 1, right? But I still have pi on that side to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve the equation $1=\frac 43 \pi r^3$ for $r$.  To do that, multiply both sides by $\frac 3{4\pi }$ and take the cube root.  The $\pi$ is just one more constant like the $3$ and $4$.